# building a stop watch with help of timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I want to add functionality to my WinForms so that when it starts a counter starts which will be in hh:mm. I know this can be done using a timer. I have made a time label which displays the current time, but I don't know how to start the timer when the form is loaded. Is there any method or class for that?

Comment: `Stopwatch` springs to mind: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Comment: Do not use code formatting to emphasize certain words. Also, post what you've done so far. Also, a Google search with the terms C# form load would have given you the answer.

Comment: So, what's wrong with winforms timer component?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i want a count down then timer can help it but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `Timer` component to your form (drag it from ToolBox - it's imporant, because timer should be registered as form's component to be disposed correctly when form closes). Set timer's `Interval` property to `60000` (that's equal to one minute). And subscribe to `Tick` event:

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (endTime < DateTime.Now)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Time is out!");
       timer1.Stop();
       return;
    }

    timeLabel.Text = (endTime - DateTime.Now).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
}
```

On [Form_Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event handler start timer and save countdown end time:

```
private DateTime endTime; // field to store end time

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    endTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120); // set countdown to 120 minutes
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: thank you sir it is decremented if i want to increament from hh:mm like 00:01 minutes and then 00:02 minutes then what i have to do?

Comment: @shariq_khan then you should save start time `startTime = DateTime.Now;` and on tick handler do `timeLabel.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm");` BTW *countdown* means decrement

Comment: @shariq_khan you are welcome, but please next time provide some code you already have - it will be useful both for you and us :)

Comment: ok. sir i will next time will be more specific. and hope you will help me next time
:)
have a nice day sir

Comment: can you help me here sir
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583036/adding-hours-from-label-and-properties-system-default

Comment: @shariq_khan I think it's already answered - when you add or substract DateTime objects you get TimeSpan (i.e. duration of time) object

Comment: OKAY i got you sir. but when storing it is not giving in proper order TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(counter_label.Text);
total_label.Text = st.Add(ts).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
but when i do this total_label.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.datetime;
it is not getting in correct order when there is total 00:00:07 then it is showing 12:00:07 why sir?

Comment: @shariq_khan I've added solution for your second answer

Answer (score 1):

The creation of a timer is very simple and straight forward:

```
Timer t1 = new Timer(); 
t1.Interval = 100; 
t1.Tick+=new EventHandler(t1_Tick);
t1.Start();

void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: sir how to post it on label.text? i dont want a simple creation of timer i want a count down timer which increments like 00:01 , 00:02 , 00:03 etc
i want a count down which starts with hh:mm then what to write in the timer tick event?

Comment: Read the documentation and play around with the source code. Then you'll find a solution.