# adding hours from label and properties.system.default

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

i have maded a counter which is a simple counter which starts from 00:00:00 and incremented in every seconds
i will provide my code for that

in the form load event i have written this

```
 private DateTime startTime; 
        private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startTime = DateTime.Now; 
            timer1.Start();

        }

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

                counter_label.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime)
.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            }
```

the timer is set to 1000 means to 1 seconds so my timer works fine
but now i want to save the label.text to the setting of the winform which is located in the properties.settings.default
so i saved the text to that by

```
private void Form7_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            DateTime st;
            DateTime end;
            st = Convert.ToDateTime(Properties.Settings.Default.datetime);
            end = Convert.ToDateTime(counter_label.Text);

            Properties.Settings.Default.datetime = counter_label.Text;
          total_label.Text = (st + end ).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");// this is not happening

          Properties.Settings.Default.datetime = total_label.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

the error is operand + cannot be applied to system.datetime and system.datetime
my intention is. when i save the text to the system properties.  at the form closing event, the new updated result must be saved which is. the old text from the system.properties and the new fromt the counter_label. how can it be done?

Comment: Are you doing sum of start and end time ??

Comment: no i am doing sum of the label.text and the text from the properties.system.default.datetime

Comment: @Ramhound The `+` operator doesn't require the result to be an integer, it's implementation dependant.

Comment: @GrantThomas how can be two hours added?

Comment: @shariq_khan - I forgot to post the link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vbgeneral/thread/6b70e1a9-5f84-4984-86b9-13040861ead6

Comment: The operator + define like this :

public static DateTime operator +(
    DateTime d,
    TimeSpan t
)

Adds a specified time interval to a specified date and time, yielding a new date and time. *you can add(+) timeSpand to dateTime only!!!!* Fix Code:

TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.Parse(counter_label.Text);
total_label.Text = (st+sp).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use setting of `string` type to store `TimeSpan` object (as Habib already stated, subtraction or addition of `DateTime` objects produces `TimeSpan`). You should create settings of type `System.TimeSpan` in `Settings.settings` file (e.g. with name TotalTime).

Saving:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.TotalTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Loading (here is trick - you are subtracting time which left from current time. So, if you have two minutes left, start time will be set for two minutes before you started applicatioin, like you never closed it):

```
startTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Properties.Settings.Default.TotalTime);
```

So, you don't need parsing any strings. Work with DateTime and TimeSpan, and let .NET to do all persisting work for you.

---

UPDATE (all code):

```
DateTime startTime;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    Properties.Settings.Default.TotalTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime);
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Properties.Settings.Default.TotalTime);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

If it is first run of your application, then `Properties.Settings.Default.TotalTime` will return default value of `TimeSpan` (which is zero time span). So, subtracting it from current time will return same value as current time.

Comment: sir you are not getting me. i want to add the hours. means when the form is closing counter_label + the properties.system.default.datetime
should be stored in the settings and on the other form i want to show the value. so i had done   
total_label.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.datetime; but when the total hour in the system.setting is 10 hrs and the counter value is 10 hours the total_label is showing 8 hours why?
so my conclusion is i want to calculate the total time the application is used.

Comment: @shariq_khan have you tried this code? :) After you set `startTime` on `Form_Load` event, label will show total time of application being used

Comment: but sir the counter function i am loosing right??
i want total time in another form. by your method at the start of app i do not get the counter i get the total time which i dont want

Comment: @shariq_khan I've added all code. And I don't understand what you want. You are talking about `total_label` then you are saying that you don't want total time. What you want to save and load?

Comment: @shariq_khan `TimeSpan`, only `TimeSpan`. BTW I renamed setting to `TotalTime` (which is more appropriate)

Comment: sir thank you very much but can you explain what is this
 startTime = (totalTime == default(TimeSpan)) ?
                DateTime.Now : DateTime.Now.Subtract(totalTime);

Comment: @shariq_khan I've added explanation for form loading handler

Comment: :) sir that was the simple if else loop right? can you form that into if else loop?

Comment: @shariq_khan I believe you can do it by yourself :) But I think ternary operator is more appropriate here, thus you are doing assignment

Comment: sir this will be ok right?
 
if (totalTime == default(TimeSpan))
            {
                startTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                startTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(totalTime);
            }

Comment: @shariq_khan yes, it is same code. Ah hold on! If we have default time span, then it's OK to subtract it without conditions! (sorry, my bad, when you are subtracting `00:00:00` from `DateTime.Now` you will have same `DateTime.Now` value. I'll update my code in a minute.

Comment: sir can i count total time from all the days? means your code counts only 24 hours but can i count how much time the total app used in a month so it will be more than 24 hours then what can be done here?

Comment: @shariq_khan change timespan string formatting to `ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm\:ss")`

Comment: that was my last question sir i cant post new question. this site is not accpeting my questions i thought i can ask new doubts
:(

Comment: @shariq_khan sorry, I don't know about site restrictions, but I think it's time to try something by yourself or to read some C# book :)

Comment: yess sir you are right but i cant get instant help which i dont know for example timespan thing i was not knowing and searching whole thing in book is just a waste of time. some guidance must be there. like you all do.. one more thing i came to know about the time span

Answer (score 2):

You can't add Two date time objects. I believe your `counter_label` has a `TimeSpan` value, since its format is `00:00:00`, You can parse that to `TimeSpan` and then add that to the your `st` DateTime type object.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(counter_label.Text);
total_label.Text = st.Add(ts).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: yes sir thank you but when i do this
 total_label.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.datetime;
it is not getting in correct order when there is total 00:00:07 then it is showing 12:00:07 why sir?

Answer (score 1):

**The operator + define like this :**

```
public static DateTime operator +(
    DateTime d,
    TimeSpan t
)
```

**Adds a specified time interval to a specified date and time, yielding a new date and time.**
****you can add(+) timeSpand to dateTime only!!!!****
Fix Code:

```
TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.Parse(counter_label.Text);
total_label.Text = (st+sp).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: but when i do this total_label.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.datetime; it is not getting in correct order when there is total 00:00:07 then it is showing 12:00:07 why sir?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two `DateTime` is not another `DateTime`, but a `TimeSpan`. So what you want to persist is not a moment in time, but the total running time, which should be a `TimeSpan`.